# Laravel job cron not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I have created job: `ServerCheck`. When I want cron this job with `php artisan schedule:run`, I get the message:

> No scheduled commands are ready to run

**Why?**

My code:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->job(new ServerCheck)->everyTenMinutes();
    // $schedule->command('inspire')
    //          ->hourly();
}
```

**UPDATE**

I get error:

> local.ERROR: Too many arguments, expected arguments "command". {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\RuntimeException(code: 0): Too many arguments, expected arguments \"command\". at

Comment: which version do you use?

Comment: Laravel 5.6, last version

Comment: Did you add the Cron entry (`* * * * * php /path-to-your-project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`) in your server?

Comment: No. I want just use command: `php artisan schedule:run`

Comment: When the `schedule:run` command is executed, Laravel will evaluate your scheduled tasks and runs the tasks that are due. <-- just in that moment, if you want it to be recurrent you'll need to add the Cron entry.

Comment: Try running it when the time is divisible by 10

Comment: Is this ‍`$ schedule-> job (new \ App \ Jobs \ ServerCheck ()) -> everyMinute ();` In the ‍`kernel.php` file in the `schedule` method ?

Comment: @Alihosseinshahabi yes.

Comment: I updated quesion..

Comment: please add `ServerCheck`class to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run the `job` when executing `php artisan schedule:run` command, you must replace `everyTenMinutes()` with `everyMinute()`

for example : `$schedule->job(new \App\Jobs\ServerCheck())->everyMinute();`

If you want the `everyTenMinutes()` code to run, you should run `php artisan schedule:run` at the following hours :

for example: 
11, 11:10 , 11:20 , 11:30 , 11:40 , 11:50 , 12:00